# Spring Boot - Jackson Fails to Convert Page Object after Upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

After upgrading from Spring Boot 3.0.0 to Spring 3.2.0, I am receiving an error for a Controller endpoint that returns a Page (from springframework.data.domain) object.

Here is the controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/reports")
 public Page<CAReportSummary> getReportSummaries(
         @RequestParam(name="open_only", defaultValue="true") boolean openOnly,
         @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page, 
         @RequestParam("start") Optional<LocalDate> start, @RequestParam("end") Optional<LocalDate> end, @RequestParam("prop") Optional<String> prop ) {

     if(openOnly) {
         return this.caService.getRequiringAction();
     } 
     
     var defStart = start.orElse(LocalDate.now().minusDays(30));
     var defEnd = end.orElse(LocalDate.now());
     if(prop.isPresent()) {
        return this.caService.getSummariesByLocID(prop.get(), defStart, defEnd, page.orElse(1));
    } 
    return this.caService.getSummariesByDate(defStart, defEnd, page.orElse(1));
 }
```

and here is an example of how the page implementation is constructed:

```
    @Override
    public Page<CAReportSummary> getRequiringAction() {
        var roles = this.authFacade.getUserRoles();
        var props = this.authFacade.getUserWorkLocs();
        var statuses = SecurityUtils.getAccessibleCAStatuses(roles).stream()
                .filter(s -> !(s.equals(CAStatus.CLSD) || s.equals(CAStatus.DSCRD)
                        || s.equals(CAStatus.INVLD)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        var res = this.caReportRepo.findByStatusIdInAndWorkLocIdIn(statuses, props).stream()
                .map(c -> this.mapReport(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new PageImpl<>(res);
    }
```

I have reviewed Spring's release notes and searched for related errors on the web, but could find no concrete resolution. I saw some issues with an earlier version of Spring (1.x to 2.x I believe) where the structure of the Page object changed when converted to JSON, but not this one.

Should I simply not be returning Spring's Page object to the client? What change caused this behavior? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the error:

```
2024-01-13 10:24:28,982 DEBUG - Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-01-13 10:24:28,983 DEBUG - Writing [Page 1 of 1 containing com.xxx.xxx.CAReportSummary instances]
2024-01-13 10:24:29,007 DEBUG - Using @ExceptionHandler com.xxx.xxx.controller.ErrorHandler#handleException(Exception, WebRequest)
2024-01-13 10:24:29,016 DEBUG - Using 'application/problem+json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/problem+json]
2024-01-13 10:24:29,018 DEBUG - Writing [ProblemDetail[type='about:blank', title='Internal Server Error', status=500, detail='Failed to write (truncated)...]
2024-01-13 10:24:29,021 DEBUG - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)]
2024-01-13 10:24:29,021 DEBUG - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-01-13 10:24:29,021 DEBUG - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2987) for a potential solution? I think you can try resolving the problem with `return new PageImpl<>(res, PageRequest.of(0, YOUR_DESIRED_PAGE_SIZE), res.size());`

Comment: Thanks so much @zypherscript. The change you proposed work. I did not see that issue, so I very much appreciate the context as well. Based on some of the comments in the Github issue, looks like it might be resolved in 3.3. In the long-term I might need to rethink my approach instead of relying on direct serialization of Page, but in the short-term, the issue is resolved. Thanks so much again!